# Strange orange orbs inside mandarin fruit

Tags: plant-health, soft-fruit, orange

[image: The mandarin in question]I'm slightly concerned with the sudden appearance of these strange orange blobs that appeared within my mandarin fruit as i was eating it. I must have not noticed them when i initially opened it. What are they? And also, should i be concerned?

Comment: Some insect laid her eggs there. Compost it or throw into your garden.

Answer (score 2):

They are definitely insect eggs.  I can't find many references of insects laying eggs on citrus fruit.  Those that do, are just under the surface, not so deep.  It is too late for this crop, most probably they all will be infected.

You need to spray for next year, before spring and maybe after fruit is formed. Ask the local garden centre.  Otherwise you can try Conqueror Spraying Oil or Neem Oil.

If you are brave, leave one fruit aside, outside and see if you can spot what hatches.

Comment: Quite bold and brave.

Comment: Now, should I be concerned that I ate half of it before I noticed this?

Comment: @Blitzwolf311 Probably not. I can't find much information about the topic online, but insect eggs end up in food on occasion anyway (think flour) and there don't seem to be any instances I can find of that causing harm. Your stomach acid should have no trouble killing the eggs, and I can't find any sources saying they're a risk for carrying toxins or bacteria.

Comment: Thank you sir. I appreciate everyone's assistance greatly.